# c# Windows Forms - buttons with texts on Data Grid View displayed half transparent. Why?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, metroframework

I have a Data Grid View and some buttons with texts on it, using Metroframework for design. The letters are somehow half transparent that the background color is seen through those letters - when the background is red it is half red and so on. In Windows Forms setting, I changed the font color - fore color to black, set opacity to 100%, and yet none of them worked. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image: how it looks]

Comment: And one more problem - sometimes when a button's clicked, not the button is clicked, but the background behind the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, it has been solved after I redownloaded the file from the repository.